# Composer PSR-0 namespaces

Tags: php, autoload

This is my actual composer.json file

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Raggaer": "app/"
    }
  }
```

My file structure is the following:

app

- bootstrap
- controllers
- views

Inside bootstrap I got **app.php** and **start.php**

**Start.php**

```
$app = new App($uri);
```

**App.php**

```
namespace Raggaer\Bootstrap;

class App { .. }
```

And im getting the following error

**Fatal error: Class 'Raggaer\Bootstrap\App' not found**